# Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I am getting this error when my site was in live when trying to show print preview dialog

```
PrintPreviewDialog ppdlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();

ppdlg.ShowDialog();
```

How can I resolve this error

Complete error

`Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.`

Comment: The message says it all: you are trying to display a dialog box from a windows service which it, by essence, non interactive. The short answer is that you can't.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.Net, you can't use PrintPreviewDialog class because it's part of windows form. The asp.net code runs on the server side.

If you want to popup a print dialog with asp.net, you have to do it on client side.

This can be achieved by a combination of a custom css for print and a bit of javascript. Here can be a good starting point : http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml

Comment: Hi actually I am creating a cheque dynamically when I click on the button a cheque was created that one I would like to show in a print preview

Comment: @Vivekh: ? my answer is valid for this scenario. create an html page with css for print, and call the print method in JS